# Error in plotting mixed design anova assumptions

Tags: r

I am trying to test the assumptions of my mixed design anova.
However, when I try to `plot()` the results I get the following error:

`Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'`

My data `def` is a dataframe and everything seems fine when I run the `View(def)` and the model doesn't report any error. The aov formula should  have all the variables and statements formulated correctly.

```r
defmodel <- aov(value~treatment_FNF*treatment_OW + Error(pId/treatment_OW), data=def)
plot(defmodel)
```

According to [Quick-R](https://www.statmethods.net/stats/anova.html) this should work. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post some data? It will make it easier to answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example